# Send string value from an acticity without builder to normal activity

Tags: java, android

I want to pass the "infor" string to the class entrar_antes_camera how can i do it?
I tried using intent but i cant put the ManagingRequests class inside the intent along the entrar_antes_camera class

```
public class ManagingRequests
{
    private void makeMaps()
    {
        this.mapped.put
        (
            "homeActions", //\MakeMaps.homeActions
            new ManagingRequests.Callback()
            {
                public void callback(String callback, String[] proposed_data) 
                    throws Exception
                {
                    JSONObject jo = comply(proposed_data).getJSONObject(0);
                    switch( jo.getString("action") )
                    {
                        case "Notification": {
                            ManagingRequests.this.db.updateAlertas(jo.getString("codigo"));
                        }
                        break;
                        case "Register": {
                            info = entry_point.getSharedPreferences("info", MODE_PRIVATE);
                            if (info.contains("cc")) {
                                String infor = info.getString("cc", "");
                                Log.i("CC INFO", infor);
                                Intent intent = new Intent (ManagingRequests.this, entrar_antes_camera.class)
                            }else
                            ManagingRequests.this.initiateRegister();
                        }
                        break;
                        case "Mirror":
                            ManagingRequests.this.showSystemTab( Asset.TIMESHEET_SUFFIX_URL );
                        break;
                        case "Schedule":
                            ManagingRequests.this.showSystemTab( Asset.SCHEDULE_SUFFIX_URL );
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        );
```

i want to put infor in this activity

```
public class entrar_antes_camera extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_entrar_antes_camera);


    }
}
```

Comment: do you want to pass a String to entrar_antes_camera class or pass ManagingRequests instance instead?

Comment: pass the string, but if a pass the instance, could i still get the "infor" in the entrar_antes_camera ?

Comment: so what is the problem of `myIntent.putExtra(String, defaultVal)`?

Comment: The problem is in the   `Intent intent = new Intent (ManagingRequests.this, entrar_antes_camera.class)`  i got this error `Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(ifractal.ManagingRequests, java.lang.Class<ifractal.entrar_antes_camera>'`

Comment: Can you show this line in your provided code, as it's not there?

Comment: I tried that but that not work, so i didnt put it there

Comment: I will put the intent that is not working to you

Answer (score 0):

The below line is causing the problem

```
Intent intent = new Intent (ManagingRequests.this, entrar_antes_camera.class);
```

AS you are putting `ManagingRequests.this` as the first argument of the `Intent` [constructor](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E)), which is not right as `ManagingRequests` is not considered a `context` as it doesn't extend from `AppCompatActivity`. The Intent constructor first argument expects a context instead.

So to solve this, In order to launch `entrar_antes_camera.class` activity, you need to add the current activity context (which is not mentioned in your question) as the first argument to the Intent Constructor instead of `ManagingRequests.this`.

Comment: Understood, but how can i do it? Because i tried doing like this `Intent intent = new Intent(infor, entrar_antes_camera.class);` and it didnt work

Comment: @LuccaGermano so in order to launch an activity (say Activity B), you have to move from some activity which is the current activity displayed on the screen (say Activity A) to that activity; the first argument of the `Intent` constructor should be the context of Activity A, and the second argument should be ActivityB.class you got it?

Comment: @LuccaGermano for more info please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application) out